# Powershell: For each folder, append all file names

Tags: powershell, file, foreach, directory

I am searching through folders in a directory and outputting their names in an Excel file.
Now I would like to list all files contained per folder (in one string).
How can I write the file names into "Masken" in $UserObject?

I want my Excel to look like this:

```
Datum      |Nummer|...|Masken
2020-01-01 | 43   |...|filename1, filename2
2020-02-05 | 44   |...|filenamex, filenamey, filenamez
```

This is my Powershell script:

```
$Folder="C:\DATEN\Powershell"
$FolderNames=Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Directory| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Daten = ForEach($FolderName in $FolderNames){

    $UserObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject | Select-Object Datum,Nummer,Art,Programmierer,Name,Masken
        
    $UserObject.Datum = $FolderName.Substring(0,10)
    $UserObject.Nummer =  ($FolderName.Split(' '))[1]
    $FolderName = $FolderName.Substring(14)

    If($FolderName -like "M*" ) { 
    $UserObject.Art = 'Modul'
    }

    If($FolderName -like "F*" ) {
    $UserObject.Art = 'Programmierung'
    }

    $FolderName = $FolderName.Substring(2)

    $UserObject.Programmierer = ($FolderName.Split(' '))[0]
    $UserObject.Name = ($FolderName.Split(' ', 2))[1]
    $UserObject
  
}

$Daten | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "$env:Temp\daten.csv" -UseCulture -Encoding Default
& "$env:Temp\daten.csv"
```

Comment: do a `G-CI` on the current dir, select just the name value, and then use `-join ', '` to make that list into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$Folder="C:\DATEN\Powershell"
$ResultFile="$env:Temp\daten.csv"

Get-ChildItem $Folder -Directory | %{

    $UserObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject | Select-Object Datum,Nummer,Art,Programmierer,Name,Masken
        
    $UserObject.Datum = $_.Name.Substring(0,10)
    $UserObject.Nummer =  ($_.Name.Split(' '))[1]
    $FolderName = $_.Name.Substring(14)

    If($FolderName -like "M*" ) { 
    $UserObject.Art = 'Modul'
    }
    ElseIf($FolderName -like "F*" ) {
    $UserObject.Art = 'Programmierung'
    }

    $FolderName = $FolderName.Substring(2)

    $UserObject.Programmierer = ($FolderName.Split(' '))[0]
    $UserObject.Name = ($FolderName.Split(' ', 2))[1]

    #your search i think
    $UserObject.Masken=(Get-ChildItem -File).Name -join ', '
    $UserObject
  
} | Export-CSV -NoType $ResultFile -UseCulture -Encoding Default

& $ResultFile
```

Comment: Thank you, this is basically what I want. Yet, the difficulty that I'm having is getting the file names not from the $Folder, but from the sub-folder (of $Folder) that I am currently parsing.

Comment: I am trying this, but to no avail:     $UserObject.Masken = ($_ Get-ChildItem -File).Name -join ', '

Comment: Turns out I am stupid. The solution is:     $UserObject.Masken = (Get-ChildItem $_ -File).Name -join ', '                  Thank you very much!